# Ilustrator stopped showing selected anchor points and round corner option

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bezier-curve

I'm not sure what I did, but it seems like I can't see what anchor points I'm selecting with the direct selection tool. I can't round corners either, as the round corner dot doesn't appear. I can actually select them, as hitting the delete button does delete them. Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

**Edit**: I did some more tests, and it looks like it doesn't work within the particular document, for some reason. If I copy a path from that document and paste it into another one, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably accidentally hit CMD+H (View> Hide Edges/ Show Edges) on your original document.

And then when you open a new document it will default to have the Edges (Selections) showing again.

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thanks!